# Naming case classes in Scala

Tags: scala, scala-2.8, case-class

I tend to have this redundant naming in case classes:

```
abstract class MyTree
case class MyTreeNode (...)
case class MyTreeLeaf (...)
```

Isn't it possible to define Node and Leaf *inside* of MyTree?
What are best practices here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since class, trait and object names are package scoped, why not use the package to provide insurance against aliasing with other nodes and leafs and call them simply `Node` and `Leaf`, while leaving them outside any other scoping construct (i.e., an object)?

Comment: What is the difference between package and companion object?

Comment: Package objects are scopes that can hold any kind of Scala entity, particularly those that cannot really appear at the top level / globally due to JVM restrictions. You can put `def`, `val` (or `var`) and `type` declarations in package objects but only traits, classes and objects at the top level. Companions are class / object pairs (that share a name) and which are defined in the same source file. Companions can access each other's private members.

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't recommend putting the case classes inside their abstract superclass because nested classes are path dependent in Scala. If anything, you could put them inside a companion object.

```
abstract class MyTree
object MyTree {
  case class Node (...) extends MyTree
  case class Leaf (...) extends MyTree
}
```

(note: I haven't tested this...)